# Git get updated files

Tags: git, tomcat

I'm starting a new job as developer, so far i'm the only one contributing to the project which is basically working on a project from another company that devleoped it on maven so i have to get their archetype and start editing,adding classes (java).
Since i've never used git, succesfully i added my own repo on github, and the process of editing (correct me if i'm wrong) is to edit->commit->push.
The final product must me deployed on a remote server and deployed on tomcat; my question is: do i have to git clone every time, i commit new modifications?Or is there a faster way?
Than on the remote server i compile it and push the war files in the tomcat server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `git clone` is only executed once to clone the server repository into your local machine.

Once you make changes to the source code, you can `git commit` command to save changes to your local repository. After that, you can use `git push` command to push your local commits from local repository to remote repository.

#### Update

You can use `git pull` command to get the latest files from remote repository to your local repository.

Comment: yes that iis what i normally do to update my project.
My question is: on the remote server, i have alredy done the git clone, if after that, i had to modify some files on the project, how do i syncronize the project on the remote server with my updated repo on github ?

Comment: After modifying, you need to commit the changes in local repository. To sync, you can use `git push`. If you are already performing the steps then I'm not sure, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: mmmh from my laptop i'm editing,updating my project correctly using commit than push.
Since the final product is alredy on the remote server with the git clone, what do i have to do in order to get the updated files, if i did some modification after the git clone through my laptop?

Comment: You can use `git pull` command to pull the latest version from remote repository.